# Json Data Request from Web using Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am new in python. Now I am studying web scraping using request but I am stuck in get data table in json format on link below

http://hyd-app.rid.go.th/hydro3d.html

Anyone can help 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click then inspect in Chrome or Firefox you can see under the network tab a XHR request is made to a different URL. You can access the URL directly like this (just update the "data" payload to what you want)

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://hyd-app.rid.go.th/webservice/getDailyWaterLevelListReport.ashx?option=2"
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
data = {"DW[UtokID]": "3",
"DW[TimeCurrent]": "23/10/2561",
"_search": "false",
"nd": "1540287188732",
"rows": "1000",
"page": "1",
"sidx": "indexcount",
"sord": "asc"}

r = requests.post(url, data = data, headers = headers)
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(r.json(), outfile)
```

I have dumped it to a file as my terminal will not display the json with the encoding it uses.